# transition у дочернего элемента при наведении на родителя

Tags: css3, transition

Добрый день! не пойму как заставить дочерний элементы плавно появляться, если я навожу на его родителя.. он появляется, но плавного изменения прозрачности не наблюдается..
Вот ссылка: http://jsfiddle.net/sGxgv/

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: никто не сталкивался с этим??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство `display:none` излишне, у вас и так `opacity 0`. Уберите его и все будет работать.

Comment: В мое случае это меню, и я не могу убрать display: none. Или использовать visibility?

Comment: элемент не будет отображаться, т.к. у него opacity:0 - не надо visibility или display

Comment: как не будет? элемент будет отображаться с нулевой прозрачностью..

http://jsfiddle.net/aAHtH/

Comment: 0 и 1 отличаются ровно на единицу

Answer (score 2):

В случае с меню (когда нельзя, чтобы "невидимый" блок воспринимался как часть родительского блока (т.е. при наведении на невидимый блок он не должен появляться) - уменьшайте его высоту или ширину.

```css
.main {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: black;
}
.ok {
    
 width: 250px;
 height: 50px;
 background: red;
 display: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; 
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
.main:hover .ok{ 
 opacity: 1;
    
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="ok"></div> 
</div>
```

В примере видно, что если вы будете наводить мышку на область ВНЕ родительского блока - пункт меню будет "проявляться", что, в случае с меню, - бред

А вот так - мы сворачиваем блок до нуля, таким образом имитируя display: none;
Заодно и анимашка прикольная ^_^

```css
.main {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: black;
}
.ok {
    
 width: 0px;
 height: 50px;
 background: red;
 display: none;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; 
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
.main:hover .ok{ 
 opacity: 1;
    width: 250px; //ЗДЕСЬ ЦЕЛЕВОЙ РАЗМЕР
 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="ok"></div> 
</div>
```